# Text Color in PowerPoint Add-in

Tags: c#, text, add-in, selection, powerpoint

Does anyone know how to change the color of a selected range of text within a powerpoint add-in using C#?

Answer (score 2):

or just:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = c.ToArgb();
```

where 'c' is your Color-element.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're using interop...

```
 var app = new ApplicationClass();
 app.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
 var myPresentation = app.Presentations.Open("c:\\test.pptx",
 Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
 Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
 Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

 var slide1 = myPresentation.Slides[1];
 var range = slide1.Shapes[1].TextFrame.TextRange;
 range.Font.Color.RGB = -654262273;
```

And don't forget to

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(<your com objects here>)
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for a solution:

I had the same problem. After spending some time figured out this way,

```
var paragraph1 = oTxtRange.Paragraphs(1);
paragraph1.Text = "Test ";
paragraph1.Font.Color.RGB = BGR(Color.Black);

var paragraph2 = oTxtRange.Paragraphs(2);
paragraph2.Text = "Application ";
paragraph2.Font.Color.RGB = BGR(Color.Green);

private int BGR(Color color)
{

 // PowerPoint's color codes seem to be reversed (i.e., BGR) not RGB, so we have  to  produce the color in reverse

 int iColor = (color.A << 24) | (color.B << 16) | (color.G << 8) | color.R;
 return iColor;
}
```

I hope this helps!