# C# and Powerpoint integration : problem defining colors

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

I use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint` to generate powerpoint files from a C# application.
I'm on Office 2007 SP2.

I generate charts, and I want to defines the colors of my series with something like this:

```
serie.Border.Color = Color.Red.ToArgb();
```

and I do this with different colors.

My problem is that when the slides are generated, the colors are not the same : when I define a serie in Red, it is drawn in Blue, and the Blue is rendered in Red. (The green stays green).

Isn't the `ToArgb()` the method to use when I want to send a color to powerpoint?
Do I have to use an other method from the Color type, or is there a manual conversion to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across the same problem a few years ago. It really is strange and I couldn't find any documentation about it, but basically, red and blue are mixed.

Back then, I wrote these methods:

```
public static int ToBgr(this Color color)
{
    return ToBgr(color.R, color.G, color.B);
}

public static int ToBgr(int r, int g, int b)
{
    //  & 0xFFFFFF -> Strip away alpha channel which powerpoint doesn't like
    return Color.FromArgb(b, g, r).ToArgb() & 0xFFFFFF;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
serie.Border.Color = Color.Red.ToBgr();
```

Comment: Typical Microsoft ... C# API contains properties RGB not BGR ... dementia

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and figured out a working solution. I have posted the answer in this link, that might be helpful if anyone is still having trouble.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18794046/2752556